# Why TypeError when too many / too few args in Python function call

Tags: python, api-design

I'm having trouble understanding why Python raises a `TypeError` when you provide arguments that aren't part of a method signature.

Example:

```
>>> def funky():
...    pass
... 
>>> funky(500)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: funky() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I thought, if this is because `*args` is expected to be `None` or `[]` within the scope of a no-arg function, that's a [leaky abstraction](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/), so I looked it up.

#### What I found

A page search for `TypeError` on [PEP-3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) found what appeared to be justification for one context in which `TypeError` is raised, but I don't understand the justification. The PEP's example is essentially stating that the functionality is basically a shortcut for `if args: raise TypeError()`. `args` is a non-empty list in that case as opposed to an empty list... which are both of the same type. If I'm not mistaken and that *is* indeed the justification, perhaps a `ValueError` would be more appropriate. However, that would still be sort-of a leaky abstraction since the example is written in Python, making it more of an implementation detail of a certain use case than a language feature. Something like `ArgumentError` sounds much more appropriate here to me, which leads me to believe there is some obvious explanation that I missed as to why `TypeError` makes sense.

Comment: Maybe because, semantically, a function/method signature is part of its "type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function takes `n` arguments. You provided `m`. `n != m`. That's propably a bug in someone's code or a symptom of someone's misunderstanding of some API. Also, I don't think we could agree on meaningful, useful semantics what should happen in this case. Should superfluous arguments be ignored? That would let such bugs pass, and since "errors shall never pass silently", that's not acceptable. Similarily, supplying some default value for omitted arguments permits silent misbehaviour in the case of typos etc. and thus violates the same principle, not to mention that "explicit is better than implicit", i.e. if you want to pass some special value you should just write that out.

The PEP you refer to and it's `if args: raise TypeError(...)` semantics apply only to functions with keyword-only arguments that don't accept varargs and use a plain `*` in the parameter list to codify this. There are functions that accept a limited number of positional arguments and would benefit from keyword-only arguments but varargs wouldn't be meaningful for them. For these, plain `*` exists to allow keyword-only arguments without requiring boilerplate code and still notify the programmer in case someone provides too many arguments (which is a good thing for reasons listed in the first part of the answer).

As for why `TypeError` was chosen: "Wrong number of arguments" is a *compiletime type error/type mismatch* in static languages. We don't have compiletime checking for such things in Python, but it's still kind of a "type error". If the (in Python, informal) type signature says "I take two arguments" and you provide three, that's obviously a violation of that contract. `TypeError` doesn't just mean `not isinstance(x, expected)`, like much other typing-related topics (just think inheritance and "gets parent's stuff" vs. "is-a parent") it's a much broader concept.

Edit in response to your criticism of the static typing comparision: Considering an unary function different from a binary function isn't just an abritary limitation of static type systems. It's very useful even in languages like Python, since the two aren't similar enough to be used "as if they walked and quacked alike" (as in duck typing) - they can't be used in the same way. (The exception, metaprogramming which wraps functions of abritary arity, is handled by the `*` and `**` unpacking operators.) They happen to share the fact that they're callable, but they're incompatible even if Python's builtin object hierarchy doesn't create numerous identical classes that only differ in arity and thus name. `type(f)` may say `function`, but that's not always the end of the story.

Comment: @delnan - so, this is a leaky abstraction, no? Why would a Python programmer be concerned with what happens in a static language (regarding practical purposes, not theory or education)?

Comment: @orokusaki: It's not a leaky abstraction. There's nothing static underneath Python that could leak anything like this. It's a deliberate design decision: The "type" - to the extent Python has types - of a function includes it's signature. Since we don't type names, this signature mostly consists of presence and number of positional and keyword argument, but *that* is part of the type of a function.

Comment: @delnan - if it's not a leaky abstraction, then I should be able to `type(some_function)` and get an signature arguments-specific type, no?

Comment: @orokusaki: You **can** inspect the signature of a callable object, e.g. by looking at the members of `code` objects. `type` doesn't do this because it simply gives you the class of an object. And creating an extra class/"type object" for every possible combination of the parts of functions signatures (e.g. `Function2ArgsVarargsKeywordArgs_foo_bar`) is wasteful and utterly useless.

Comment: @delnan - I'm enlightened by your answer as to why Python does things this way (I didn't know this much about the static-related stuff), but the more you explain it, the more it sounds like a leaky abstraction to call it a `TypeError`. The innards of Python's handling of the situation have not to do with the function API, right? Though exposed through various low-level tools, introspection, etc, are the implementations of function definition and function calling not distinct from the API?

Comment: @orokusaki: It **is** a type error. Regardless of any implementation details. Take a deep breath and step away from the `type` function and consider "type" more broadly, in the sense it is used in Python: An object of type T is something that does X, Y and Z ("An object is a duck if it walks and quaks like a duck"). A binary function is something that processes two arguments. An unary function doesn't do that, hence it's of a different type. They're both *implemented* with the same C code but work differently - It's actually the opposite of a leaky abstraction!

Comment: And as for why one needs to dig so deeply and use introspection to get information about the arity: For the same reason you have to do these things to get the name of an object's class or the source code of a function - because most code shouldn't have to actively read this information and act on it. It should instead call functions with the right number of arguments.

Comment: @delnan - I understand. I'm not debating what `type` or duck-typing are and how they work. The function call doesn't reveal a `TypeError` from below. It creates the `TypeError` itself. I can't just *accept* this per se. I want to know how a `TypeError` in the implementation that one wouldn't know about without reading some docs on the implementation, or without introspection doesn't represent A) a leaky abstraction (I suppose more so in the situation where the implementation re-raises the `TypeError` vs the API creating it) or B) the wrong exception to raise. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @orokusaki: The exception `TypeError` to be is raised when, well, a type error is encountered. And calling a function with the wrong number of arguments *is* a type error, as the arity is part of the type. Period.

Answer (score 0):

You said:
def funky():
  ...
So the program "funky" should not take any 'arguments'. But when you used the program, you said funky(argument), and funky does not take arguments, so that caused the error. To fix this, use; def funky(n): pass .