# Python: reason for TypeError with wrong number of arguments

Tags: python, exception, typeerror

I recently bumped into a "feature" of Python which I found not really well thought-out: Python raises `TypeError` if a function is called with the wrong number of arguments. I would like to understand what is the reason behind this choice.

**Further details:**
I find myself setting-up a callback system and, among other things, I check if a (user-defined) callback can accept or not an argument. I have to check this up-front when I am given the callback, because if I simply do something like:

```
try:
    call_the_callback(one_argument)
except TypeError:
    call_the_callback()
except Exception:
    do_something_else()
```

I find myself in the uncomfortable situation of catching also a `TypeError` thrown by the inside-workings of the callback (maybe it expected a string instead of an integer, or something), which I definitely need to discriminate.

In the end, I bypassed this with a check as follows (I guess this is only for Python 3):

```
callsign = signature(action)
nargs = len(callsign.parameters)
```

and then using the appropriate call. However, apart from this specific problem, I simply cannot understand why putting under the same umbrella a call with the wrong number of arguments and, say, `1 / "three"`.

**NOTE:** I understand why an error is raised for a call with the wrong number of arguments, I definitely want that! My problem is with understanding why a `TypeError` is raised and not something more specific. I want to have a deeper understanding of this to better design strategies to tackle this kind of situation.

**References**:

Too generic, only saying that a call with the wrong number of arguments is "some kind of `TypeError`": [Why TypeError when too many / too few args in Python function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191501/why-typeerror-when-too-many-too-few-args-in-python-function-call)

Discusses the issue but does not answer the question: https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/45841-incorrect-number-arguments

Comment: Can you explain *why* the answer to the other question you've linked doesn't answer your question? What part of your question is not answered?

Comment: Also it appears that your *actual* question is how to determine the number of arguments of a function programmatically. This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218616/getting-method-parameter-names-in-python

Comment: @mkrieger1 I know how to determine the number of arguments, and that is actually mentioned in the question.

Comment: I take it that your issue is not that Python insists that the number of parameters be correct, but that when it isn't, you see a `TypeError`, rather than, say, a `WrongNumberOfParametersError`. Is that it? If you consider the number of parameters to be a kind of tuple, then passing a3-tuple to a function that is expecting a 2-tuple is a kind of `TypeError`.

Comment: @BoarGules That's right, I do want an error, but I do not like the `TypeError` class for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I think almost all programming languages have mandatory parameters for a function and if those parameters are not received an exception is raised. This is good for enforcing a proper usage for that function. If function parameters are not mandatory you need more handling logic inside the function in order to cover all cases.

But you can use optional parameters or generic parameters along with or without mandatory params.
For example bellow is a function which allow you to have any number of parameters (simple or keyword parameters) and no param is mandatory:

```
def f1(*args, **kwargs): 
  print args
  print kwargs
f1(1,'param', a=4)
```

For more details see: 
[generic function in python - calling a method with unknown number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147737/generic-function-in-python-calling-a-method-with-unknown-number-of-arguments)

Comment: I know that, but unless I miss something, this is quite irrelevant to the question. The point is that I have no control over the function that has to be called, and I have to live with that.

Comment: If you define the function with non-mandatory parameters the TypeError won't  be raised anymore and the function will be executed regardless the number of parameter received. Please give more details/rephrase if this info doesn't help you.

Comment: As discussed above, I am fine with raising an error with the wrong number of arguments (actually, I want that), the issue I have is with the kind of error raised, i.e., TypeError.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure that you can change the type of exception raised or if is recommended to do that because is something language specific. However if you call your function from multiple places I recommend to use non-mandatory parameters and handle the use cases inside the function in order to prevent parameters duplicate handling logic/code. Either way calling a function on purpose with a wrong number of parameters and try to catch the exception if not quite a best practice in my opinion.

Comment: Agreed, but that does not change the fact that catching in the same way a call with the wrong number of arguments and `1/"three"` is an at least equally bad practice to my eyes.